# Defining variables

Tags: python

If the user has inputted `'tea'` or `'t'` as their choice, how do I define the variable `beverage.lower()` as `'tea'`? Because of the

```
if beverage.lower()=='t'or beverage.lower()=='tea':
                beverage.lower()=='tea'
```

line has absolutely no whatsoever effect on the overall program itself?

```
while True:
        beverage=raw_input("What is your preferred beverage: coffee, or tea?")
        if beverage.lower() not in ('coffee','tea','t','c'):
            if beverage.lower()=='t'or beverage.lower()=='tea':
                beverage.lower()=='tea'
            elif beverage.lower()=='c'or beverage.lower()=='coffee':
                beverage.lower()=='coffee'
            print("Sorry! I didn't quite catch that. Please try again! (Note that you can use the letter 'c' or the letter 't' to denote coffee or tea respectively!)")
            continue
        else:
            print("Ah! Fantastic choice!")
            break
```

Likewise, how would I go about defining the user inputted `beverage.lower()` as another variable?

Comment: the expression `beverage.lower()` means you call the method `lower()` of the instance of the string class. So you can do what you want.

Comment: Do not mix 4 tabs and 8 tabs indentation.

Comment: Why not just lower it once? `beverage = beverage.lower()`

Comment: @Vineeth Sai: That's referred to as tabs of 4 spaces and tabs of 8 spaces—but you're right that they should not be mixed together in the same code.

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the correction, Updated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code had various issues in flow control(`if` blocks) and value assignments( `==` and `=`). After some changes, here it is.
And try not to mix tabs of 4 spaces and tabs of 8 spaces. Always stick to 4 space tab as it is standard from **PEP8**

```
while True:
    beverage = input("What is your preferred beverage: coffee, or tea?").lower() # much efficient to .lower() only once
    if beverage in ('coffee','tea','t','c'): # Change this to 'in'
        if beverage == 't' or beverage == 'tea':
            beverage = 'tea' # value assignments are done with = not ==
        elif beverage == 'c' or beverage == 'coffee':
            beverage = 'coffee' # value assignments are done with = not ==
        print('Ah! Fantastic choice!')
        print('You have chosen {}'.format(beverage))
    else:
        print("Sorry! I didn't quite catch that. Please try again! (Note that you can use the letter 'c' or the letter 't' to denote coffee or tea respectively!)")
```

**O/P:**

```
What is your preferred beverage: coffee, or tea?c
Ah! Fantastic choice!
You have chosen coffee
What is your preferred beverage: coffee, or tea?t
Ah! Fantastic choice!
You have chosen tea
What is your preferred beverage: coffee, or tea?x
Sorry! I didn't quite catch that. Please try again! (Note that you can use the letter 'c' or the letter 't' to denote coffee or tea respectively!)
```

Comment: I see my problems now. I appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

just use the variable to assign value:

```
if beverage.lower()=='t'or beverage.lower()=='tea':
    beverage = 'tea'
```

assigning another variable:

```
input_var = None
beverage=raw_input("What is your preferred beverage: coffee, or tea?")
if beverage.lower()=='t'or beverage.lower()=='tea':
    input_var = 'tea'

print 'Input value: ', input_var
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the statement `beverage=beverage.lower()` if you want to modify the value of the variable `beverage`.

From your question I believe that was your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

`if beverage.lower()=='t'or beverage.lower()=='tea':
                beverage.lower()=='tea'`

**Above statement has no effect as you said, because you have written it so.**
If input is not in ('coffee','tea','t','c'), there is absolutely no chance it will go under above code.

You need to replace `if beverage.lower() not in ('coffee','tea','t','c'):` with

`if beverage.lower() in ('coffee','tea','t','c'):`

Also you need to replace `beverage.lower()=='tea'` with `beverage.lower()='tea'` inside the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You are making a small mistake while assigning the value 'tea' or 't'.
It should be like -
beverage='tea' instead of beverage.lower()=='tea'

Comment: What does `beverage.lower() = 'tea'` do?

Comment: My mistake it should be beverge='tea'.

Comment: If you realise your mistake you can improve your answer.